# summarize code without making too many arguments in R

Tags: r, functional-programming

whenever I see some repetition pattern in my code I feel there must be a way to summarize it. here is an example in R which I'm struggling with:

```
if( all(auto.file.flag) ){
    save_dirs = c(basename(father_vcf_file),
                  basename(mother_vcf_file))
    for(save_dir in save_dirs){
        loc = file.path(save_dir, 'dual_analysis_results')
        dir.create(loc, recursive=TRUE)
        write_csvy(father_res, file.path(loc,father.out.file))
        cat(child.out.file,'saved.         \n')
        write_csvy(mother_res, file.path(loc,mother.out.file))
        cat(parents.out.file,'saved.         \n')
        fwrite(res_sumary_ord, file.path(loc,summary.out.file), sep='\t')
        cat(summary.out.file,'saved.         \n')
    }
}else{
    write_csvy(father_res, father.out.file)
    cat(father.out.file,'saved.         \n')
    write_csvy(mother_res, mother.out.file)
    cat(mother.out.file,'saved.         \n')
    fwrite(res_sumary_ord, summary.out.file, sep='\t')
    cat(summary.out.file,'saved.         \n')
}
```

*the code explanation*: if `all(auto.file.flag)` save the three results in two different directories (the directory names are generated based on some other variables) if not save them without attaching any directory to the output file names.
if I replace the repetition part with a function, the functions would have 6 or 7 arguments. I'm new to functional programming but I feel there must be some better approaches for this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why would they need that many? Consider that you could create a vector of the names.

Comment: @Elin the arguments of the function should include all the three result objects (because the saving function is different between them) plus their location to be saved.

Comment: That sounds like 4.

Comment: Although this might be a special case because of working with character variables I encounter similar situations that within a function I want to replace a bunch of code with another function but the arguments would become too much. I thought maybe there is some R functionalities which I'm not aware of.

Comment: Yes for example, your cat() functions are all the same and take one argument.  You should just feed it a list of the values of that one argument.  You could then use lapply.  That is a simple first step.

Comment: thanks, if I use lapply in that case all `cat` functions would run consecutively but I want them to be exactly after the write functions. (if write functions were the same that might have worked)

Comment: No I don't believe that's right. I'm not seeing any reason that they have to come in that way. But even if they do, write a simple function to manage that. Also you are doing a lot of things in loops that don't need to be. For example just create loc once.

Comment: each time `loc` is created in another place based on `save_dir`

Comment: Exactly, so since you have th values of save_dir in the sav_dirs vector, just reference them rather than retyping.

Comment: So the key is to just try different ways of seeing your procedural code as something that contains variables and you want  to manipulate them as abstractly as you can. And then your code will become easier to manage and read as well as faster..

Answer (score 0):

The way to make this better in my experience is to go step by step, thinking about where you are duplicating and how you can increase the abstration.

```
newcat <- function(filename){
   cat(filename,'saved.         \n')
}

filenames <- c("name1", "name2", "name3")

 lapply(filenames,newcat)
```

Since you do that in both branches, put it at the end
and do them all at once.

```
if( all(auto.file.flag) ){
    save_dirs = c(basename(father_vcf_file),
                  basename(mother_vcf_file))
    for(save_dir in save_dirs){
        loc = file.path(save_dir, 'dual_analysis_results')
        dir.create(loc, recursive=TRUE)
        write_csvy(father_res, file.path(loc,father.out.file))
 
        write_csvy(mother_res, file.path(loc,mother.out.file))

        fwrite(res_sumary_ord, file.path(loc,summary.out.file), sep='\t')

    }
}else{
    write_csvy(father_res, father.out.file)

    write_csvy(mother_res, mother.out.file)
   
    fwrite(res_sumary_ord, summary.out.file, sep='\t')
    
}
 lapply(filenames,newcat)
```

Then keep going with each one, think about replacing your hard coding as much as possible.  Make a data frame or vectors with all of the things like the file names.

```
if( all(auto.file.flag) ){
    save_dirs = c(basename(father_vcf_file),
                  basename(mother_vcf_file))
    locs = file.path(save_dirs, 'dual_analysis_results') 
    for(save_dir in save_dirs){

        dir.create(locs[save_dir], recursive=TRUE)
        write_csvy(father_res, 
                file.path(locs[save_dir],father.out.file))
 
        write_csvy(mother_res, 
                file.path(locs[save_dir],mother.out.file))

        fwrite(res_sumary_ord, 
             file.path(locs[save_dir],summary.out.file), sep='\t')

    }
}else{
    write_csvy(father_res, father.out.file)

    write_csvy(mother_res, mother.out.file)
   
    fwrite(res_sumary_ord, summary.out.file, sep='\t')
    
}
 lapply(filenames,newcat)
```

Comment: thanks. I still see the repetitive part. is there anything like a function within a function that have access to the parent function variables and you can specify the behaviour of the function with the arguments?

Comment: Yes you can do things like that.  I  think though that there is a lot you can do, for example notice that you could create this vector: c("father.out.file", "mother.out.file",  "summary.out.file")  since you use that twice.